# App crashing while trying to store data on Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

App Crashing with error:

> FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users_table has 1

I am trying to store like this:-

```
func updateFirestorePushTokenIfNeeded() {
        if let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken {
            let usersRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("users_table").document(userID)
            usersRef.setData(["fcmToken": token], merge: true)
        }
    }
```

My firestore is empty right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message almost certainly means that `userID` is nil or empty.  You should verify that you're passing the correct values to Firestore.